# Extracting Redundancy in Predicate

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

```
var listOfAs = new List<A>();   
var listOfBs = new List<B>();
listOfAs.AsQueryable().Where(PredicateForA(6));
listOfBs.AsQueryable().Where(PredicateForB(5));

private Expression<Func<A, bool>> PredicateForA(int value)
    => x => x.B.C.D.Value == value;
private Expression<Func<B, bool>> PredicateForB(int value)
    => x => x.C.D.Value == value;
private Expression<Func<C, bool>> PredicateForC(int value)
    => x => x.D.Value == value;
private Expression<Func<D, bool>> PredicateForD(int value)
    => x => x.Value == value;
```

I'm wondering if there's an option in c# to extract and re-use the predicate for selecting the value.
The idea is that I only have PredicateForD and use it with specifying on which nested object should it be used on:

```
listOfBs.Where(x => PredicateForD(5, x.C.D));
```

But I can't really figure something that works that way.
Does C# supports that kind of predicate nesting?

Edit: Predicate methods are way more complicated than that, they can have 70+ lines of code, and those are multiplicated by every nested object there is.

Comment: `.Where( x=> x.B.C.D.Value == 4)` ? nice and short, expressive and explicit, no need to have those predicates

Comment: I agree with @TheGeneral, Why would you need to nest predicates so much? predicates are supposed to be quick, easy to read and maintainable. Nesting them just defeats their purpose and makes it very hard to read. If you have a complex task, use a class.

Comment: You can build the expression yourself combining "nested" ones but I think that in such simple case it is not worth the effort and will only reduce readability and maintainability.

Comment: @TheGeneral , That would work for the simple predicate, but when the logic is way complicated and predicate method needs 70+ lines of code it is basically multiplicated by every time the object is nested. The fact that maybe there's an error on the approach is a different story.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use the normal for..each loop constructs.... LINQ isn't always the best choice

Comment: It would help if you would show us the real predicates. Maybe this is a  XY problem (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Predicates with 70+ lines? Woww!

Comment: @CallumLinington: he needs an `Expression<predicate>`.

Comment: Depending on your use case - this library might help: https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The real case is fetching data via Entity Framework, Hierarchical structure creates cases when we need to query for data with similarly looking predicates. They were very long and complicated so we decided on creating moving them to separate methods and in fact, we are repeating the logic on the same object but the nested level is different. And instead of calling x.value == 5, we need to dig deeper into x.a.b.c.d.value == 5.

Comment: @Evk at first glance, https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-expression-variables-in-subqueries this looks like worth checking, thanks!

Comment: [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) with `AsExpandable` or `Invoke`/`Expand` is definitely the way to go.